# python, pysfml. No encode to text

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

i want drawing the russian text in pysfml, but i get error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import sfml as sf
import json
class draws:
    def __init__(self):
        with open('setting.json') as data_file:    
            setting = json.load(data_file)
        print
        self.window = sf.RenderWindow(sf.VideoMode(setting['window_width'],
                                                   setting['window_height']),
                                                   setting['title'])
        self.run()#bot
    def run(self):
        font = sf.Font.from_file("arial.ttf")
        text = sf.Text("Русский текст", font, 16)#this error string
        while self.window.is_open:
            for event in self.window.events:
                if type(event) is sf.CloseEvent:
                    self.window.close()
            self.window.clear(sf.Color.BLUE)
            self.window.draw(text)
            self.window.display()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Tree = draws()
```

Console error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal
not in range(128)

I use unicode:

```
text = sf.Text(u"Русский текст", font, 16)#this error string
```

exelent, but wrong drawing literals.
[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMZpZ.png)
I use cp1253(russian codec)

```
text = sf.Text(u"Русский текст".encode('cp1253'), font, 16)
```

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: cha
racter maps to

```
text = sf.Text(u"Русский текст".decode('cp1253'), font, 16)
```

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordin
al not in range(128)
English text exelent draw.
I now not see as this job.

Comment: Not familiar with `sfml`, but to get the image error, you have UTF-8-encoded text being decoded as `latin1`.  so that's a clue.

Comment: No, i use UTF-8 - encode, this first my act. i use .encode('utf-8') end get same storage error. I think how sf.Text read first 128char only unicode string. I decided this remap ttf font coping russian literal in reserv zone ascii. Look pydocs https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html chapter "The Unicode Type"

Comment: To get that image error, the characters displayed are **literally** what you get when displaying UTF-8-encoded text as `latin1`.  `sfml` looks like it *expects* `latin1` instead, for whatever reason.